# Jenkins should not proceed if Execute shell fails

Tags: jenkins

I have a Maven project configured and it has an execute shell section as "Pre Steps"  and after that I am building a POM in "Build" section.

I need an option to fail the MVN build execution if a command in execute shell fails. If a shell command in Pre Step fails, it should not proceed further and it should fail the job immediately without proceeding to other section in the job.

Could anyone help me on this?

Comment: How is the "_command in execute shell_" related to the Maven build that should fail if the command fails?

Comment: My Requirement is .... Checking a condition in pre steps execute shell section, and if the condition fails, the job should not proceed and execute MVN project in the same job. It should come out of the Jenkins.

Answer (score 1):

Jenkins will stop execution if `Execute shell` exits with non-0 exit code.

Remember that by default Jenkins is executing shell (pre-)build steps using `/bin/sh -xe`, where `-e` means to exit with failure if any of the commands in the script failed.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the shell script have like this

```
exit_status=`your command`

if [exit_status != 0]
exit 1;
```

Please note that i provided only the flow. not with exact syntax.